# Using Lagrange's Theorem to compute the possible orders of subgroups of $H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

To figure out the possible orders of subgroups of $H$, I use Lagrange's theorem by computing all the possible divisors of $|H$|, correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What you say after "I use" is simply the Lagrange theorem. Hard to see wht you are asking. Surely you don't mean "Is Lagrange's theorem correct"?---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Lagrange theorem, if $G$ be group of finite order then order of its any subgroup must divide order of G.
But, Converse statement is not true always.

Ex- $\mathbb{A}_4$ (Collection of all even permutations on set of 4- symbols) has order 12. But there is no subgroup of order 6.
Remember,
If $G$ is finite  abelian, then you will get subgroup of each divisor.
for,finite abelian group , converse is true.